# Is streaming server required for internal videos?

Tags: java, video-streaming

We are going to develop a training web application in java. For that we need to upload the videos in the application server. If the user count increases for the videos the application server is hanging. So we need to develop a controller so that if any increase in the user count(user requests) to the videos the controller should process the video requests without affecting the other users. Is there any open source software to control the broadcasting of the videos in internal application server ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your question is a little bit confusing.

Comment: my question is apart from web server do we need any streaming server to handle the video requests from multiple users?

Comment: If you are looking for open source streaming media systems, this link may be helpful. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_streaming_media_systems